# JQuery Stack of Cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a stack of cards. They are stacked so each one has about a centimetre at the bottom visible. What I want, is when a card is clicked it moves to the right, then gets sorted to the top and moves to the left back onto the pile. I then wish to trigger a page change (to the page that's represented by the card).

How would I do this through JQuery? I'm still at a basic level with this language.

```
<style>
#cardStack{
    height: 700px;
    width: 400px;   
    overflow:visible;
}
#cardStack ul{
    display:inline;
}
#cardStack li{
    z-index:auto;
}
.top{
    margin-top:-670px;
    z-index:1;

}
.middle{
    margin-top:-670px;
    z-index:2;
}
.bottom{
    margin-top:100px;
    z-index:3;
}
</style>
</head>

<body><br /><br />
<div id="cardStack">
<ul>
    <li class="bottom"><img src="images/cardA.png" /></li>
    <li class="middle"><img src="images/card6.png" /></li>
    <li class="top"><img src="images/card8.png" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I know there's an animate function, but how would I initiate this on a click?

EDIT: Added more code above

Comment: then could I do this through the Z-Index property?

Comment: @Ghommey does the OP mention rotation?

Comment: @El Ronnoco: `They are stacked on an angle...`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I meant that the bottom of each card is visible. Not actually on an angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the hash change use [ben alman's BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) 
tried your code at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)
but because the link to the cards is missing the HTML doesn't render right
if you put here a working jsbin sample - helping you will be mush easier

concerning the animations: if you layout the Li's to have an absolute position, you can move them around freely,
so you can animate them to the left and then animate back and then change the z-index to put it on the top

[edit]
So.. [here is a link to a quick solution](http://jsbin.com/ecewa3/3/edit):
you had some problems with the animations code, + better to change the position and not the marign

for ref the code:

```
$('#cardStack img').click(function () 
{
       var img = $(this);
       img.animate({left: '+=50px'},200,function() 
          {
                img.animate({left: '-=50px'},200,function()
                     {
                       img.parent().prependTo($("ul"));
                       arrengeClasses();
                     });
          });
});

function arrengeClasses()
{
    var allListItems = $("#cardStack ul li");
    for(var i=0;i<allListItems.length;++i)
    {
      allListItems.eq(i).removeClass().addClass("pos" + i);
    }
}
```

- and changed the css a bit:

  ```
   #cardStack li img{
      position:absolute;
       top:0px;
       left:0px;
      }
   .pos2{
      z-index:1;
      margin-top:100px;
   }
   .pos1{
      z-index:2;
      margin-top:50px;
   }
   .pos0{
     z-index:3;
   }
  ```

Comment: If I could vote you up again, I would! It works great, cheers

Comment: Similar question. How would I modify the information in a separate div depending on which card was on top? Cheers

Comment: happy to help :), you have control on the click event, so when clicking on it just $("targetDiv").text() or $("targetDiv").html().       get the text according to the ID of the image or according to some attribute on the element, it can be data-contentUrl='someUrl' and then load the Url via ajax and populate your div

Answer (score 3):

You can set an event to occur on any of the images being clicked like:

```
$('ul li img').click(function () {
    $(this).animate( ... );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I can't give any more specific help without knowing the CSS you are using to "stack" the cards.

Answer (score 1):

As for the part where you want to trigger a page change, you can use `window.location` to append a hash to the end. So your URL might end up being `example.com/cards#joker`